# Target called automatically in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my `UITableView` I've many cells created like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
   let btn = cell.viewWithTag(1001) as! UIButton
   btn.tag = indexPath.row
   btn.addTarget(cell, action: Selector(myFunc(btn)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

...
}
```

I can't understand why myFunc() is called automatically when the UITableView is populated. (without touching any buttons)

Comment: Which Swift version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Swift 2.2

Comment: try moving your `btn action Method`  to didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is never called

Comment: do you have another btn action inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath?` or show us more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `addTarget` method something like this

```
    btn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(myFunc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: PS: can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Because you given the target of the function in the cell, so target call automatically in the cellRowAtIndexPath without touching any button. First you remove cell from the target and write self. It says the function declare the same class. If you access function from any other class then write the class name.

```
  btn.addTarget(self, action: Selector(myFunc(btn)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```